# Pass variables between methods

Tags: c#, methods

I have 2 methods in my program. 
1. Start Exam
2. Mark Exam

as you see, 
in first method i calculated how many questions are correct or wrong.

in second, i want to show the result.

PROBLEM:
How can i pass the correctlyAnswers and wrongAnswers and LIST between methods?

this is what i have:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int menuChoice = 99;
        Question[] questions = new Question[30];


        do
        {
                Console.Clear();

                DisplayMenu();

                menuChoice = InputOutput_v1.GetValidInt("Option");

                switch (menuChoice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        InputOutput_v1.DisplayTitle("Start Exam");
                        CreateQuestion(questions);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        InputOutput_v1.DisplayTitle("Mark Exam");
                        DisplayAllQuestions(questions);
                        break;
        }

        } while (menuChoice != '0') ;
    }

    public static void StartExam(Question[] questions)
    {
        char[] studentAnswers = new char[30];
        int[] wrongAnswers = new int[30];
        int correctlyAnswered = 0;
        int falselyAnswered = 0;
        string list = "";

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("== DO NOT CHEAT! ==\n");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nQuestion {0}", i + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            questions[i].DisplayQuestion();

            studentAnswers[i] = InputOutput_v1.GetValidChar("Your Answer (A, B, C, D)");

                if (studentAnswers[i] == questions[i].correctAnswer)
                {
                    correctlyAnswered = correctlyAnswered + 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    falselyAnswered = falselyAnswered + 1;
                    wrongAnswers[i] = i + 1;
                    list += i + 1 + ", ";
                } 
        }
    }
    public static void MarkExam(Question[] questions)
    {

        if (correctlyAnswered >= 15)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Passed with {0} correct answers", correctlyAnswered);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed with {0} incorrect answers. Incorrect answers are: {1} ", falselyAnswered, list.Remove(list.Length - 2));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the correctlyAnswers, wrongAnswers, and LIST defined as global variables outside your methods, e.g.

```
private int correctlyAnswered;
private int falselyAnswered;
private Question[] questions;
```

Comment: how can i pass them into the methods? it would be public static void StartExam(Question[] questions, int correctAnswers, int wrongAnswers, string list) ?

Comment: using global variables you don't need to pass them into the methods, you can just declare the variables outside the methods. Then you can access those variables in any method inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why can't you call your `MarkExam()` method passing those variables like

```
public static void StartExam(Question[] questions)
{
    char[] studentAnswers = new char[30];
    int[] wrongAnswers = new int[30];
    int correctlyAnswered = 0;
    int falselyAnswered = 0;
    string list = "";

    ........
    MarkExam(questions, wrongAnswers, correctlyAnswered);
```

In which case you will have to change your method signature accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using an array instead of a list? And inside this class your methods don't really need to be static.

Second, create private variables to the class and they can be used in all methods.

```
public class ExamClass
{
    private List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
    private List<Question> incorrect = new List<Question>();
    private List<Question> correct = new List<Question>();

    ...
}
```